# NoSuchElementException and SyntaxError during web-scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am having some difficulties in applying this suggestion to fix the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./ancestor-or-self::form"}
```

got when I use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

query = ' I want to try to translate this text'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions('/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://translate.google.com/')
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#source')
search.send_keys(query)
search.submit()
```

As explained here: [NoSuchElementException - Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190910/nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element), I should use something like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("source"));
```

But I get a SyntaxError (due to `WebDriverWait wait =` ).

I have tried also to follow these answers:

[NoSuchElementException (SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451572/nosuchelementexception-syntaxerror-too-many-statically-nested-blocks)

[Selenium Webdriver - NoSuchElementExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739319/selenium-webdriver-nosuchelementexceptions)

but I am still getting errors:

```
try:
    search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#source')

    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    time.sleep(1)
```

gives me `break outside the loop`; whereas this

```
try:
    search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#source')

except NoSuchElementException:         
    pass
```

does not change anything (still gives me the error: `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./ancestor-or-self::form"}`)

Could you please help me to find a way to fix these errors?

Update: I also tried to use `driver.implicitly_wait(60)` and I have got the same `NoSuchElementExpection` error.

More detail on the error:

```
---> 23     search.submit()
     24 
     25 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in submit(self)
     83         """Submits a form."""
     84         if self._w3c:
---> 85             form = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor-or-self::form")
     86             self._parent.execute_script(
```

Comment: `new` is not a python keyword !

Comment: Thanks. But I have got this code from a previous answer accepted. probably it was for a different programming language.

Comment: The error is about `"selector":"./ancestor-or-self::form"` but yet your code doesn't ever select this element

Comment: Not really clear why you need selenium at all... https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

Comment: It was asked me to use selenium for scraping it (I know about googletrans but unfortunately I cannot use it)

Comment: You're not really scraping here, though. You're using the web UI to make the same API request that that library would do.

Comment: My question is different: it is on how to fix this issue. I am doing web-scraping but the part of code related to that part is not relevant for fixing this issue. I think I followed all the guidelines and I do not understand why to down vote the question

Comment: You could try `textarea#source` or a function other than `find_element_by_css_selector` since the error is related to XPath parsing, but the issue lies within Selenium, I'm guessing, not your code

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer. Unfortunately textarea#source does not work. I think there is some part related to xpath which is missing

Comment: The wait is in java language instead of python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done everything wright in your code shared at top except this line: `search.submit()`. As you are calling `submit()` method of web element and element search defined by you is no form rather its an `Textarea`,hence `NoSuchElementException` . Because submit method is applicable for only `form` type of elements. If you remove this line your code will work just fine.

from selenium import webdriver

```
query = ' I want to try to translate this text'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions('/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://translate.google.com/')
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#source')
search.send_keys(query)
```

**Output**
[image: Browser View of Output]

**Note :**

To know how to use different wait mechanisms in selenium python, below could be a good read:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="source" class="orig tlid-source-text-input goog-textarea" rows="1" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="overflow: auto hidden; box-sizing: border-box; height: 70px; padding-bottom: 18px;"></textarea>
```

Xpaths can be either:

```
//*[@id='source']

/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/textarea
```

Basically wait for an element and send the query and hit submit.

```
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( 
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, //*[@id='source'])) 
search.send_keys(query)
search.submit()
```

Also add these

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```